# "Разонеметь"? Или как образовать от глагола "онеметь" противоположное по значению слово

Tags: орфография, словообразование

В словарях слова "разонеметь" нет, но можно ли придумать что-то схожее по смыслу с противоположным значению "онеметь", - то есть прекратить быть немым?

Comment: Я «отнемела», потерянно глянула на врача и всё же решила попытать счастья ещё раз.

Answer (score 2):

1. Слишком хитро, заговорить проще, побеждает более простое.
2. И кроме того это попытка создать что-то не из отрицания, а из несуществования не-м(не говорит, а мычит или вроде того), то есть двойное отрицание, конечно, в теории логики должно давать что-то, но тут это видимо не работает, так как чего-то нет. Немой это уже 0, от того что вы будете менять знак у 0 он единицей не станет. С другой стороны есть слово чары - очаровать это воздействовать чарами на кого-то - а разочароваться, значить прервать воздействие. Но немой - это про вообще отсутствие звуков, тут логика право-лево не работает, это другая координата.

То есть в логике есть координата право и лево - количественная координата и направление воздействия на что либо, ненулевое по "модулю" воздействие. И прибавляя префиксы можно менять характер воздействия, в разумных пределах.

Однако, есть и другая координата - качественная, когда что-то либо есть, либо его нет или оно является чем-то другим. Вот тут не получится вернуть первоначальный вариант, реку которая уже впала в озеро не повернуть вспять.

бредовое дополнение:

Наткнулся на значение приставки раз/рас и корня раз/роз, так вот они обозначают различие, разницу, когда что-то врозь(имеет одно начало, но выражает другую сторону). Если брать сочетания с *О - разо*, то, например разодеть - раз+одеть - раз+о+де+ть(де - то что одевают, вещи, о - значит соответствовать некому целому, как любят говорить сторонники буквицы - образ, то есть создание *образа в надетых вещах*), то раз говорит об усилении эффекта одевания, также как, например, бежать - разбежаться(увеличить скорость бега), болеть - разболеться / либо это завершение начатого действия рвать - разорвать (разделить), где **раз - это даже не части от деления, а сама линия раздела**, то есть, когда режете пирог, то *раз* это сам разрез, а не куски пирога, граница деления. Мне кажется, это понятие имеет очень глубокие философские корни и связано с Великим Пределом(в Ин-Яне, если вы внимательно посмотрите, не две части - противоположности, о которых так много сказано, а есть еще четкая граница их разделяющая, то есть на самом деле знаковых элементов 3 - противоположности и граница между ними, но западная философия все сводит к бинарным конструкциям вроде право-лево, добро-зло, морально-аморально. так вот раз - это и есть граница между причиной и следствием, буква И, та что сидела на трубе с А и Б)... То есть *разонеметь* должно значить еще большее онемение (или его предел, переходящий во что?) - замолчать еще тише, был человек немой, а тут совсем говорить перестал??

В английском, да и скорее всего латинской группе языков используется другая приставка - dis-(которую любят переводить как раз-) , означающая как раз противоположность данному, другой кусок. Dishonest - не-честный, как видите, приставка раз- не подойдет ни к одному значению слова honest (честный, добросовестный, правдивый, порядочный, искренний...). Или, например, dis+allow - запрещать, при том что allow - это как раз разрешать, то есть давать пользоваться подами решения, и ни решать, ни разрешать не находятся в оппозиции. Возьмем другое разнять(нять это какое-то древнеславянское брать) - разобрать на части, опять нет противоречия с действием брать, а скорее его логический финал, следствия "брания". То есть приставка *раз/рас*(или корни) не имеет значения противоположности(хотя при поверхностном восприятии кажется что мы имеем дело с противоположными вариантами), за исключением очень странных слово вроде "*раскреститься*" - креститься назад (что по православному канону, кстати, невозможно, то есть этот обряд по сути бессмысленный). Хотя в английском есть похожее слово - distinct - различать, однако тут dis- не считается приставкой.

Что же касается *разлюбить*, то, вероятно, это слово задумывалось не как прийти к ненависти, а как дойти до предела любви, растратить любовь, прекратить любить, как нести и разнести.

Ну и в завершении про такое "непереводимое понятие" как discourse, которое почему-то некоторые считают разговором, discourse(нет направления) - отсутствие, уход от первоначального курса, темы, за её приделы допустимого "обсуждения", "беготня вокруг". В то время как цель разговора как раз попытка эти общие моменты нащупать, ввиду их отсутствия. То есть мы вроде приходим к одному и тому же "смыслу", но совершенно разными путями - дискурс, это уход от шаблона, разговор - попытка нащупать общие темы. Однако, любому русскому понятно, что хождение вокруг да около разговором ну ни как не будет, а будет пустой болтовнёй, попыткой увильнуть в шаблонную или менее шаблонную схему надувательства, так что в серьёзном разговоре вопрос часто ставится ребром, а в дискурсе часто забалтывается.

Вывод из всего этого следующий: **раз - не является приставкой противоположного значения (в отличие от dis-), раз - это развитие, разделение, линия разреза, следствие воздействия.**

Вот так, казалось бы очевидные вещи, не являются не то что неочевидными, а являются совершенно иными с точки зрения логики восприятия у людей разных культур.

Comment: @shampar спасибо, хотя сложно так тире ставить, но конечно длинная черта эстетичнее. А над примером еще подумаю, правда мимо, бывает)

Comment: @shampar Нет, без "0" не работает.

Comment: Пардон, oleedd, надеюсь Буратино ещё не проверял и не пытался: тире —  alt+0151.

Comment: @shampar проверил - у меня нет нампада), как на ноуте врять альт + что-то не знаю

Comment: @Буратино можете скачать Punto Switcher для автозамены на длинное тире (ну и остальные знаки)